# Why is my Bluetooth headset producing a hissing noise?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones, bluetooth-speaker

I have a pair of Bose QC35's, and they work fine on my iPhone/iPad and on Windows, but when I connect them to Ubuntu, the bluetooth connection works, but whenever I play some audio, a lot of garbled hissing noise is made. I have set them up again and again using the default connection interface, and with blueman. I am using Ubuntu Gnome if that is important. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you try to adjust the headphone wire?

Comment: They're wireless.

Comment: The volume may be too high, just like other speakers and headphones

Comment: It happens at all volume levels, and the hissing increases whenever I raise the volume.

Answer (score 2):

In the sound settings, use `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)` mode for the headphones. The hissing will stop.

One caveat is that the headphone's microphone won't work in this mode. [This might be an issue with the headphones themselves](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-3153126/bose-qc35-mics-work-set-headset-static-sound.html). I experience the same issue with android when I get a call (android uses A2DP by default and switches to HSP when you get a call).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a while now. For me the problem was fixed today by a firmware update of Bose. In the Bose Connect application I installed the update (happens over Bluetooth), after which the hissing sound was gone.