# Bose QC35 mic on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones, microphone

Recently I bought Bose QC35, and they are super, however, I'm going through a bit of trouble setting them up on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

With the help of several AskUbuntu answers, I managed to connect the headphones to the PC, but one thing that I din't manage to find is how to make use of the headphones' mic when on call. Currently the internal mic, which is really bad, is used, and when I try to change it in sound input settings I hear an annoying squeaky noise, and the sound output changes from High Fidelity Playback mode to Headset Head Unit. It is unbearable to have headphones on my head for 30s because of this squeaky noise, so I am looking for a solution to still use headset's mic while not loosing my ears.

Comment: Did you try to manage settings with `pavucontrol` application?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same microphoone problem with slack calls and also I have 16.04 LTS and QC35. BT music streaming (A2PD) is working perfectly and also when someone calls during streaming, I am able to use headphone microphone too (at least this was OK earlier before re-install of ubuntu due to another issue).

When during a call I selected QC35 in pavucontrol, then slack did not complain any more about missing audio input. BUT even if I did hear audio very well, my voice was not send.

Even if I select HSP/HFP (=BT call audio profile) at configuration tab of pavucontrol, I see only "monitor" of my QC35 as input device (as well default built-in audios). 
Also testing sound (front left, front right) seems to use only A2DP because did not hear any sound degradation when tried to change profile to narrow band HFP.

~/.config/pulse$

cat xxx-default-sink 

bluez_sink.BT_ADDRESS

cat xxx-default-source 

alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo

(Thus the source did not change even if tried)

Also btmon shows only ACL packets (instead of expected SCO), thus assuming that only A2DP connection is running.

update: Re-starting pulseaudio solved the problem, i.e., now able to use also mic and see those in pavucontrol those as expected. 
And passed tests:
https://add_here.slack.com/help/test/calls

Unfortunately HFP seems to cause some noise but that is another problem, already discussed at [bluetooth-headset-producing-a-hissing-noise](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937370/why-is-my-bluetooth-headset-producing-a-hissing-noise)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 18.04 but this has worked for me on the last few kernels.
In `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` set `ControllerMode = bredr`